# Change tables in function

Tags: postgresql, function

I try to change working between tables in one function. But I get error message.

ERROR: column "t1010" does not exist.

Here is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION history_check_test (temp1 text DEFAULT '', temp2 text DEFAULT '', temp3 
text DEFAULT '', temp4 text DEFAULT '', temp5 text DEFAULT '',
temp6 text DEFAULT '', temp7 text DEFAULT '', temp8 text DEFAULT '',
temp9 text DEFAULT '', temp10 text DEFAULT '', temp11 text DEFAULT '',
temp12 text DEFAULT '',temp13 text DEFAULT '', temp14 text DEFAULT '',
temp15 text DEFAULT '',temp16 text DEFAULT '',furnace_nr integer default 1)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

declare

lastCGTime integer;

_command text  := 
'select max(%1$I) as One, max(%2$I) as Two, max(%3$I) as Three, max(%4$I) as Four ,max(%5$I) as Five,
 max(%6$I) as Six, max(%7$I) as Seven ,max(%8$I) as Eight 
,max(%9$I) as nine ,max(%10$I) as Ten ,max(%11$I) as Eleven, max(%12$I) as Twelve, 
max(%13$I) as Thirteen, max(%14$I) as Fourteen ,
max(%15$I) as Fifteen, max(%16$I) as Sixteen, date_trunc(''minute'',"TimeStamp_Measure_Cycle_Local") as 
 Timestamp_Measure_Cycle_Local from %17$I
inner join "T_Measure_TimeStamp" on "T_Measure_TimeStamp"."ID_TimeStamp_PK" = %17$I."ID_TimeStamp_FK"  
group by TimeStamp_Measure_Cycle_Local order by TimeStamp_Measure_Cycle_Local;';

BEGIN 
lastCGTime:=8;


execute format(_command ,temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10, temp11, temp12, temp13, temp14, temp15, temp16, 'Table_1_Furnace_' || furnace_nr);
execute format(_command ,temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10, temp11, temp12, temp13, temp14, temp15, temp16, 'Table_2_Furnace_' || furnace_nr);
execute format(_command ,temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10, temp11, temp12, temp13, temp14, temp15, temp16, 'Table_3_Furnace_' || furnace_nr);
execute format(_command ,temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10, temp11, temp12, temp13, temp14, temp15, temp16, 'Table_4_Furnace_' || furnace_nr);

      
return lastCGTime ;
END;

$function$
;
```

In the "Table_1_Furnace_1" table have columns t1 - t1000, "Table_2_Furnace_1" t1001 - t2000,
"Table_3_Furnace_1" t2001 - t3000, "Table_4_Furnace_1" t3001 - t4000.

If i run the function and I like to get back information from different tables like:

```
select history_check_test ('t1010','t2300','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8','t9','t10','t11',
't12','t13','t14','t15','t16','1');
```

I get error message hogy not found the t1010 column ( because that is in the Table_2_Furnace_1 table, not in all of them. )
Some reason always want to check how this info in all of the tables not just only one.

Have any way to fix this in one function or I need to write all of the tables in separate query?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how you thought this would ever work? It is premised on Postgres ignoring columns that don't exist in a particular table and that is not going to happen. You will need to create a query for each table.

Comment: If I create 4 different query still if not found one column in the another query, i get error message.

Comment: Well yeah, each query is going to have to only use the columns appropriate for the table being queried. Postgres is not going to magically do this for you.